# Jquery - How Table Tools export as xls?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm using DataTables and TableTools to format a table
and when I want it to export the table as .xls the result
is still as .csv. .pdf export works flawless but how to make "TableTools"
to export the table as .xls?

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use libs like:
http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/ or
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Or you can use header to make simpel xls files

```
$filename ="excelreport.xls";
$contents = "testdata1 \t testdata2 \t testdata3 \t \n";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: sorry i just found my misatke

Answer (score 2):

try this, problem solved.. :)

```
$('#dt_gal').dataTable({ "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip', 
"oTableTools": {"sSwfPath": "<?php echo base_url() ?>asset/export/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" ,
"aButtons": [
   "copy", 
   { "sExtends": "csv", 
     "sTitle": "titleExport csv",
     "sFileName": "*.csv" 
   },
   { "sExtends": "xls", 
     "sTitle": "titleExportxls",
     "sFileName": "*.xls" },
   { "sExtends": "pdf", 
     "sTitle": "titleExportpdf",
     "sFileName": "*.pdf" 
   },
   "print" ] } 
});
```